# How to make a POST request by passing values to the request body?

Tags: scala, playframework, http-post

I want to pass a list of IDs to a POST request.

```
def exportByIds = 
    Action.async(parse.tolerantText) { req =>
        ids = req.body.split(',')
        download(ids)
    }
```

In the routes file it looks like this.
`POST  /games/export/_ids controllers.Game.exportByIds`

Here I also didn't understand what the _ before ids meant.

So the function doesn't accept a parameter. Instead it gets the parameter from the request body. But how can I pass a value to the request body inside a form?

```
form(
    noFollow,
    cls := "button",
    action := s"${routes.Game.exportByIds}",
    method := "POST"
)
```

I tried to do the POST request with ws but when creating a function I cannot pass it to the action parameter because there is a type mismatch.

Comment: `_ids` in the route path doesn't have any meaning, it's just the path you or your team chose.

Comment: If you use forms, you'll need to adjust a bit the backend route to handle form data as input rather than just plain text as currently. Or, don't use form in the frontend and just use plain JavaScript to make a call to the backend.

Comment: See also https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaForms